# Detecting a null value using a ClientHandler in a Google Apps Scripts GUI

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm coding a GUI using Google Apps Scripts.  I have a text box, for example txtLastName and I would like to add a Client Handler to detect a null value.  Essentially, I want to make this a required field.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are a few possibilities, one of them is to use a length validator

```
var clientHandler = app.createClientHandler().validateLength(widget, min, max)
```

and to use this to `setVisible` a warning message and to disable the 'submit button' eventually...

the [documentation on clientHandlers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_clienthandler) is quite explicit

Here is an example in a simple form that checks `question 1` and displays a warning message :

```
function BuildForm() {
  var text= new Array();
  text =['question 1','question 2','question 3','question 4','question 5','question 6']; 
  var textBox = new Array();    
  var app=UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Form');
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('panel');
  var btn = app.createButton('process');
  var warning = app.createLabel('You forgot to fill in question 1').setVisible(false)
  for (nn=0;nn<text.length;++nn){
    var label = app.createLabel(text[nn]);
    textBox[nn] = app.createTextBox().setName(text[nn].replace(' ',''));
    panel.add(label).add(textBox[nn])
  }
    var cliH1 = app.createClientHandler().validateLength(textBox[0], 0, 1)
        .forTargets(btn).setEnabled(false)
        .forTargets(warning).setVisible(true)
    var cliH2 = app.createClientHandler()
        .forTargets(btn).setEnabled(true)
        .forTargets(warning).setVisible(false)

  var servH = app.createServerHandler('process').addCallbackElement(panel).validateLength(textBox[0], 1, 40)
  btn.addClickHandler(cliH1)
  textBox[0].addClickHandler(cliH2)
  btn.addClickHandler(servH)  
  panel.add(btn).add(warning)
  app.add(panel)
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app)
}


function process(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication()
      Browser.msgBox(e.parameter.question1+'  '+e.parameter.question2+'  '+e.parameter.question3+'  '+e.parameter.question4+'  '+e.parameter.question5+'  '+e.parameter.question6)
      app.close()
      return app
          }
```

EDIT : here is another version using another validation (validateMatches) and checking all answers

```
function BuildForm2() {
  var text= new Array();
  text =['question 1','question 2','question 3','question 4','question 5','question 6']; 
  var textBox = new Array();    
  var app=UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Form');
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('panel');
  var btn = app.createButton('process').setWidth('240');
  var warning = app.createLabel('You forgot to fill at least one question').setVisible(false)
  for (nn=0;nn<text.length;++nn){
    var label = app.createLabel(text[nn]);
    textBox[nn] = app.createTextBox().setName(text[nn].replace(/ /g,''));
    panel.add(label).add(textBox[nn])
  }
  var servH = app.createServerHandler('process').addCallbackElement(panel).validateLength(textBox[0], 1, 40).validateLength(textBox[1], 1, 40).validateLength(textBox[2], 1, 40)
      .validateLength(textBox[3], 1, 40).validateLength(textBox[4], 1, 40).validateLength(textBox[5], 1, 40);
  var cliH = app.createClientHandler().validateMatches(textBox[0],'').validateMatches(textBox[1],'').validateMatches(textBox[2],'').validateMatches(textBox[3],'')
      .validateMatches(textBox[4],'').validateMatches(textBox[5],'')
        .forTargets(warning).setVisible(true)
  btn.addClickHandler(servH).addClickHandler(cliH)  
  panel.add(btn).add(warning)
  app.add(panel)
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app)
}
```